# get url from error in retrofit2 and rxjava

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, rx-java2, rx-android

I'm using retrofit 2 with rxjava to send rest requests. and Gson as json parse.

if Gson cannot parse json string then throws `java.lang.IllegalStateException` with some message. my issue is that i don't know this error happened on which url.

if error type is `HttpException` i can get url from that but in other types like `java.lang.IllegalStateException` and `TimeoutException` just access to error message is available and i can't see the url.

how can i achieve to url in rxjava and retrofit catch.

that's my code:

```
mainApi.getSomething(offset, limit, distance, latitude, longitude)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe({it:Response<Something>
                val entities = it.body()?.entities
                callBack.onResponse(it.raw(), entities)
            }, {//it:throwable
                if (t is HttpException) {
                   Log.d("logUrl", "HttpException : ${t.response().raw().request().url()} : ${t.code()} :${t.message()}")
                } else//something like IllegalStateException or TimeoutException
                     Log.d("logUrl", "Failure : ${t.localizedMessage}")
                })
               })
```

Comment: if(t instanceof  HttpException){
                   Log.d("path",((HttpException) t).response().raw().request().url().url().toString());
                }....

Comment: @kubersingh that's what i do. i want a solution for other types of exception

Comment: ok, i am using callabck way, i always get error response on  
@Override
    public void onFailure(Call call, Throwable t)  methods

Comment: yes if use callback, Call instance is available, but in RxJava ...

Answer (score 6):

### new Consumer() method always provide a message on any type of error even if GSON error

```
 mGetDeviceObserver.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
         .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(new Consumer<RegData>() {
    @Override
    public void accept(@NonNull RegData mRegData) throws Exception {
    }
}, new Consumer<Throwable>() {
    @Override
    public void accept(@NonNull Throwable t) throws Exception {
       if(t instanceof HttpException){ Log.d("path",((HttpException) t).response().raw().request().url().url().toString()); }
    }
});
```

Comment: I think this will help you

Comment: your answer is just for HttpException that i already wrote in my code. if any other exception type happened Throwable will receive but because this is not HttpException then i can't see what url throws this error.